# Why can I pass a char to a method that takes an int?

Tags: java

```
Class Example{
static void go(int a)
{
    System.out.println(a);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    go('c'); //prints 99
}
}
```

But, if i change the  method to static void go(byte), gives error:The method go(byte) in the type Example is not applicable for the arguments (char).

Comment: `char` is 16 bits while a `byte` is 8 bits. That said, you can cast a char to bye (you lose data): `go((byte)'c');` but I don't see any value in doing so.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I assume OP is *trying* to learn Java.  Let's be helpful, not mean.

Comment: @dimo414 I understand and that's exactly why I said that... I have mentored many in programming and I have observed that most of them will try to take shortcuts... so that they can "make their code run" in the short-run... And they try avoid a seemingly more boring part of trying to understand the language... which harms them and only them in long run.

Comment: I just want to make sure to remind them to go back to understanding "boring" concepts... just making the code work is not everything.

Comment: A mentor who tells me to go "learn java" is a mentor I'm better off without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's due to Widening Conversion or Implicit Casting**

> If a value of narrower (lower size) data type converted to a value of
>   a broader (higher size) data type without loss of information, is
>   called Widening conversion. This is done implicitly by the JVM and
>   also known as implicit casting. For example an integer data type is
>   directly converted to a double.

**Example**

```
int a = 100; 
double b = a;
System.out.println(b);
```

In above example `integer (4 Byte)` converted into `double (8 Byte)`

> Widening conversion is allowed in the following cases:

- byte can be converted to short, int, long, float, or double
- Short can be converted to int, long, float, or double
- char can be converted to int, long, float, or double
- int can be converted to long, float, or double
- long can be converted to float or double
- float can be converted to double

[image: Implicit Type Casting]

Now Coming to

> But, if i change the method to static void go(byte), gives error:The
>   method go(byte) in the type Example is not applicable for the
>   arguments (char).

This is due to **Narrowing Conversion**

> If a value of broader (higher size) data type converted to a value of
>   a narrower (lower size) data type which can result in loss of
>   information, is called Narrowing conversion. This is not done
>   implicitly by the JVM and requires explicit casting. For example
>   double data type explicitly converted into integer

Since  **char** is `16 bits` while a **byte** is `8 bits` So you have to explicitly cast like this :

```
char c='c';
byte b=(byte)c;
go(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

**implicit typecasting** is allowed only for **widening** not for **narrowing**.
int can be implicitly type cast to long but reverse is not possible. for that you have use **explicit type casting**.

Answer (score 0):

int can fit into 32 bits, while a char is only 16 bits. It is implicitly converted into an int without losing any accuracy.

However, a byte can only hold 8 bits so you will need to state explicitly that you want to convert it with `(byte)c`. A bigger char value might get cut down into a smaller value though.